# Why the increase in starting value of $n$ when taking derivative of power series?

Tags: calculus, power-series

Why is the starting value of $n$ increased by $1$ when taking derivative of power series?

i.e.:

$f(x) = \sum_\color{red}{n=0}^{\infty} c_{n} x^{n}$

$f'(x) = \sum_\color{red}{n=1}^{\infty} nc_{n} x^{n-1}$

Comment: In that example the term in $f$ corresponding to $n=0$ is constant with respect to $x$. Namely $c_0$. The derivative of which is $0$. On the other hand, the formula for $f'$ could perfectly have the term $n=0$ being $0\cdot c_0$. It is actually more convenient to do keep the term $n=0$, although beware, you might encounter the instructor that doesn't have the proper training to see how useful it is and will try to penalize you for it.

Comment: A nice book in which you can see how elegantly manipulate power series is [Concrete Mathematics](https://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/gkp.html). There you can find [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) to not have to bother so much with those first terms.

Comment: If you write the higher derivatives of $f$ in the form $$f^{(k)}(x) = \sum_{n = k}^{\infty} \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}c_nx^{n-k}$$ it is convenient to start the summation at $n = k$ because that avoids the problem "What is $(-1)!$?".

Comment: @ConnerM. $\uparrow$ as I told you. Better advice will come from the true masters that wrote Concrete Mathematics and profit greatly from not drowning in the shallow water that is defining $(-1)!=\infty$  and $\frac{1}{(-1)!}=0$. This is also in the spirit of another great master, Leibniz. The idea that notation should serve the mathematician. Why would you want to be burdened by it?

Comment: Note: $\sum_\color{red}{n=1}^{\infty} nc_{n} x^{n-1}=\sum_\color{red}{n=0}^{\infty} nc_{n} x^{n-1}$ so you can write either one.

Answer (score 3):

The first term is $c_0x^0 = c_0$, so is constant, so its derivative is zero. If you prefer, you could re-index: 
$$f'(x) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty(n+1)c_{n+1}x^n,$$ but that's slightly more writing, so most people don't.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$f(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+...=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n.$$
Then 
$$\begin{align}
f'(x)&=\frac{d}{dx}\left(a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+...\right)\\
&=\frac{d}{dx}a_0+\frac{d}{dx}a_1x+\frac{d}{dx}a_2x^2+\frac{d}{dx}a_3x^3+...\\
&=a_0\frac{d}{dx}1+a_1\frac{d}{dx}x+a_2\frac{d}{dx}x^2+a_3\frac{d}{dx}x^3+...\\
&=a_0\cdot0+a_1\cdot1+a_2\cdot2x+a_3\cdot3x^2+...\\
&=0+1a_1+2a_2x+3a_3x^2+...\\
&=a_1x^{0}+2a_2x^{1}+3a_3x^2+...\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_nx^{n-1}.
\end{align}$$